# What's the best way to have a button come visible on a specific screen size in MVC?

Tags: button, model-view-controller

I have a ViewModel with a button. I want this button to only be visible if the screen size is 500px or less.

Whats the best way to do this?

1. An if statement at the bottom of this viewModel,
2. create a footer file and put it in there around an if statement,
3. somewhere in the CSS or
4. code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an if statement, or maybe put it in the CSS as a media query? You could hide the button normally and then unhide it/display it when the screen size is 500px in your CSS.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks!